# How to write this object access code more graceful?

Tags: typescript

I have some problems in TypeScript object access. For example, I have code like this:

```js
enum DataTypes {...}
class Cache {
    private _data: Partial<Record<DataTypes, Data>> = {};
    private getExpensiveData(name: DataTypes): Data {...}
    private get(name: DataTypes) {
        if(!(name in this._data)) {
            this._data[name] = this.getExpensiveData(name)
        }
        return this._data[name] //return type Data | undefined
    }
}
```

For now i can only write the last line of `get` as `return this._data[name] as Data`, but is there a way to write it more beautifully?

Sorry i didn't say it clearly, but i actually mean is there are way make TS can infer it not null, not more simple ways to `as` it.

Comment: `return this._data[name]!`? Or you could rearrange the logic so the compiler can infer that the value is going to be defined, e.g. https://tsplay.dev/NnboVN. But it can't narrow `this._data[name]` based on `name in this._data`.

Comment: Please provide a working minimal example that shows the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the null-coalescing operator as an augmented assignment:

```
return this._data[name] ??= this.getExpensiveData(name);
```

Since the `??` operator is short-circuiting, the right-hand side will only be evaluated if the left-hand side is `undefined` (or `null`).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAcBOBLAbmAC4Cm02JYAJvAHYgCe0VxYAXNAApjZG5ggAPACUSweNiqCIRPLQDmAGmgy58gHzroAXhQBfANyp0WPIVLR5JIgFEAHphK0IBEgBFWACgDWJBh1VcBQBKANkg+RQTDAoiAFdsWmgAA3tHZ1doABJkXwY9ZKMMPWMMTDiAIxBcYEtrDyIwHz8wtVCVcIUojBjrBKSiAAtcCAA6FkaAbTyAXWgAfnndIZHRq1sHJxd8dy884KLoEpKgA)